# Command-line options to IPython *scripts*?

Tags: python, ipython

I am often asked to debug Python scripts written by others.  I would like to send these scripts to IPython so it will drop into an IPython shell at the point the script fails.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to send (required) command-line options required by the scripts.

IPython assumes everything in  is for IPython when I pass the script and its options as:

```
ipython <script_name> <script_options>
```

Is there a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
ipython -i -c "%run test.py 1 2 3 4"
```

Comment: Very nice!  Unfortunately, when it exceptions out, it drops me back onto the OS command line, not onto the IPython prompt.  Suggestions?

Comment: Well you could just start ipython and then do %run test.py 1 2 3 4

Comment: Actually adding the -i makes it stay in the shell.

Comment: @jimbob If you don't mind me asking, where'd you find the '-i' option?  I'm having no luck finding it in 'ipython -help' nor 'http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/stable/html/interactive/reference.html'

Comment: @JS I only found it in man python (not ipython):  "-i    When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after  executing the script or the command.  It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.  This can be useful to inspect global variables or a stack trace when a script raises an exception."  Kinda frustrating it wasn't in man ipython, but gave it a shot and it worked.

Comment: Caveat:  I'm running IPython on many different machines.  Some will work with the above solution and others will not.  All report 'ipython -Version' as '0.10'. I haven't had time to diagnose why this is, but don't get caught by this like I have (several times).  If it doesn't succeed on your IPython setup, try another.

Answer (score 51):

```
ipython -- sometest.py 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: It works, but I could not find this in the docs, can you point me to where this is documented?

Comment: Also to remain within the interactive shell use `ipython -i -- sometest.py 1 2 3 4` syntax.

Comment: Note that '--' is a feature of the system shell interpreter, and is not specific to ipython shell

Comment: If you like to debug with ipdb, you can similarly use `ipython --pdb -- somtest.py 1 2 3 4`.

Answer (score 5):

I know there's an already accepted solution, but in the most recent version of ipython this won't work.  Here's a cut and paste of the command I use to run tornado tests with --autoreload

```
ipython --c="%run test.py --autoreload"
```

This is using ipython .11.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html).

**script.py**

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

**shell:**

```
$ ipython script.py stuff things that
The script is called: ex13.py
Your first variable is: stuff
Your second variable is: things
Your third variable is: that
```

Answer (score 0):

Many aspects of IPython's behavior can be controlled via settings in the user's IPython config files, which typically are in `~/.ipython/`.  A user can create multiple *profiles*, each with different settings of the config parameters. Each profile has its settings in a separate folder in the `.ipython` folder.  The default profile is in `profile_default`, and the main file in there for customizing behavior is `ipython_config.py`.  By default, it is almost entirely commented, with commented lines showing the config variables and their default settings.  Uncomment or insert lines to alter behavior.

To change how IPython behaves at the end of running a script, use:

```
c.TerminalIPythonApp.force_interact = True
```

Then when the script ends (or raises an exception), IPython will keep running and present you with a prompt.  This is the same behavior as `ipython -i`.

I use this setting in my default profile, because this is the way I *always* want IPython to behave.  If that's not the case for you, you could create a profile with this behavior, to use just when you want this behavior.  Or just keep using the (evidently undocumented) `-i` option.

IPython configuration documentation is available here:  [Introduction to IPython configuration — IPython documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#the-ipython-directory), with the `force_interact` option described here: [Terminal IPython options — IPython documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-TerminalIPythonApp.force_interact).