# Debugging a Python Script (With Flags) in Spyder

Tags: python, breakpoints, spyder

Forgive me, I'm coming from a MATALB background, and I'm still a *litte* confused at how the Python "modules" all work together.

I installed Anaconda, and I'm using the Spyder IDE with the default IPython console (I think I said that all right). I'm going through the [Google Education](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files) lessons, and I'm presented with the challenge of calling a particular code like so:

```
./wordcount.py {--count | --topcount} file
```

I figured out (thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138145/command-line-options-to-ipython-scripts)) that I could run this from IPython within Spyder:

```
%run wordcount.py --count alice.txt
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I call wordcount.py in this way from the console, it disregards any of the breakpoints I have set and I need to line-by-line step through my code. Alternatively, if I try to run the dubugger that's part of Spyder, I can't seem to specify any of those flag command line arguments.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret is to modify the **Run Settings**! Under the Run Settings > General Settings you're given the chance to run command line options. The debugger observes these additional command line options when run.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this ability has been removed, at least looking at Spyder v5.5.1. You can only set command line options when running in "external system terminal"

Comment: P.s. - Spyder v5.5.1 moved the ability further down the "Run configuration per file" dialog. You have to first select "Run file with custom configuration," and then scroll down further to get to the new location for "General Settings" > "Command line options"