# Run IPython in a script

Tags: python, shell, ipython

I am trying to do some scripting with IPython, but I am finding that it behaves very differently in a script to when I run an interactive shell.

For example, I can run the following interactively:

```
In [1]: %profile
default

In [2]: ls /
bin/   cdrom/  etc/   initrd.img@      lib/    lib64/       media/  opt/   root/  sbin/  sys/  usr/  vmlinuz@
boot/  dev/    home/  initrd.img.old@  lib32/  lost+found/  mnt/    proc/  run/   srv/   tmp/  var/  vmlinuz.old@

In [3]: mkdir tmpdir

In [4]: cd tmpdir
/home/alex/tmp/tmpdir
```

No problem.

However, none of these commands works when I run them in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ipython3

%profile
ls /
mkdir tmpdir
cd tmdir
```

I get an error:

```
$ ./tmp.py 
  File "/home/alex/tmp/tmp.ipython", line 3
    %profile
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried running this by:

1. calling the file directly as above,
2. calling it explicitly with ipython: `ipython3 tmp.py'
3. passing the `-i` or `--profile=sh` arguments to ipython when calling it with ipython
4. changing the file extension to `.ipython` and `.ipy`

**My question:**
Why is it behaving differently in a script to the shell?  How can I get IPython to run these commands in a script?

Answer (score 1):

They are working due to [IPython magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) but they are shell commands and do not work in Python. To get them consider the [`subprocess` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call). Where you would have spaces in a shell command instead have comma-separated values in the list.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['ls'])
subprocess.check_call(['ls', '-a'])
```

Comment: I was hoping to get the advantages of the IPython magic, but in a script form... is there any reason that this sort of thing should be available in a shell but not a script?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this but have you tried [importing IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding)? My understanding is that these functions are part of IPython so if you are not in that environment then you don't have access to them.

Comment: Just tried that and it had no effect.  I assumed that because I am selecting IPython as the interpreter it would be doing this anyway...

Comment: I've never seen it done in the manner you describe. That would be cool. But perhaps they wouldn't be called "magic" anymore!!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the difference... what's the difference between typing lines into an IPython shell manually, and IPython reading those same lines from a file?

Comment: I don't know how to pass text to IPython. Here is a hack. If I put this in a `test.py` file and run the file then it will run the `%pwd` command but I don't know how to run future commands. `print`?     `import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['ipython', '-i', '-c', '%pwd'])`

Comment: Link for [above ipython command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4138203/4938264).