# How to run ipython script in python?

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to run ipython script in python, ie:

```
code='''a=1
b=a+1
b
c'''
from Ipython import executor
for l in code.split("\n"):
   print(executor(l))
```

that whould print

```
None
None
2
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

does it exists ? I searched the doc, but it does not seems to be (well) documented.

Comment: Are you trying to run a notebook? :)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785742/run-ipython-in-a-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, depending on what you want to do and how much IPython features you want to include, you will need to do more.

First thing you need to know is that IPython separates its code into blocks.
Each block has its own result.

**If you use blocks use this advice**

If you don't any magic IPython provides you with and don't want any results given by each block, then you could just try to use `exec(compile(script, "exec"), {}, {})`.

If you want more than that, you will need to actually spawn an `InteractiveShell`-instance as features like `%magic` and `%%magic` will need a working `InteractiveShell`.

In one of my projects I have this function to execute code in an `InteractiveShell`-instance:
https://github.com/Irrational-Encoding-Wizardry/yuuno/blob/master/yuuno_ipython/ipython/utils.py#L28

**If you want to just get the result of each expression,**

then you should parse the code using the `ast`-Module and add code to return each result.
You will see this in the function linked above from line 34 onwards.
Here is the relevant except:

```
if isinstance(expr_ast.body[-1], ast.Expr):
    last_expr = expr_ast.body[-1]
    assign = ast.Assign(    # _yuuno_exec_last_ = <LAST_EXPR>
        targets=[ast.Name(
            id=RESULT_VAR,
            ctx=ast.Store()
        )],
        value=last_expr.value
    )
    expr_ast.body[-1] = assign
else:
    assign = ast.Assign(     # _yuuno_exec_last_ = None
        targets=[ast.Name(
            id=RESULT_VAR,
            ctx=ast.Store(),
        )],
        value=ast.NameConstant(
            value=None
        )
    )
    expr_ast.body.append(assign)
ast.fix_missing_locations(expr_ast)
```

Instead doing this for every statement in the body instead of the last one and replacing it with some "printResult"-transformation will do the same for you.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i'm looking for. Do you replace ast.Expr by ast.Assign because you can't eval them ? I've got no luck with eval(compile(l,"<string>","eval") when l is an ast.Expr .

Comment: Exactly, it replaces the last statement of the block to an assignment in case it is an expression. I can then get its result. You have to do it to each statement.

Comment: I manage to eval Epr instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819981/how-do-you-compile-an-ast-expt/52820217#52820217